# GWT - css class names

Tags: css, gwt, xcode-server

since some time I have the problem that all my css class names are obfuscated (like div.O0NPTOB-q-k) when I look at them with e.g. Firebug. This is ok for production use but not when running in dev mode (with code server).

Could anybody give me a hint how to disable that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, use :

```
<set-configuration-property name="CssResource.style" value="pretty"/>
```

in your ***.gwt.xml